# Byte Compiling Functions Using `defalias` for `progn`

Tags: elisp, byte-compilation

The following code:

```
(defalias 'new-progn 'progn)
(defun foo ()
  (new-progn "foo"))
(byte-compile 'foo)
(foo)
```

gives this error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (invalid-function #<subr progn>)
  new-progn("foo")
  foo()
```

Using `prog1` or `prog2` has a similar problem. Replacing `progn` with other special forms like `and` or `or` will not issue such an error.

Why `progn` is special in this case?

Comment: I think the byte compiler handles `progn` specially, i.e., the compiled code never calls `#<subr progn>`.

Comment: I observe the same error from `and` as from `progn`: `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (invalid-function #<subr and>)
  new-and(nil "foo")
`

Comment: @sds I see your edit. I'm using Emacs 25.2 and the error message is what I said: `Invalid function: new-progn` (which may not matter though). There is no problem using `and` or `or` in this case.

Comment: I am using e26; please feel free to revert my edits.